# How to get current timestamp in VLC player without using gui?

Tags: vlc-media-player, automation, autohotkey

I need to automate vlc player and need to get current timestamp for that. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @duDE command line, creating text file, getting it from builtin http server, etc. Not API.

Comment: @duDE Any way that is usable for AutoHotkey.

Comment: AutoHotkey means you're using Windows, yes?

Comment: @grawity Yes. I use windows 8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/marq/):

```
% vlc --sub-filter "marq{marquee=\$t (\$P%%),color=16776960}:marq{marquee=%H:%M:%S,position=6}" somevideo.avi
% vlc --sub-filter 'marq{marquee=$t ($P%%),color=16776960}:marq{marquee=%H:%M:%S,position=6}' somevideo.avi
```

This command line will show the stream's title ($t) and current position ($P) in the upper left corner **and the current time in the upper right corner**.

Comment: This prints the current time of the day, and not the timestamp of the particular scene/frame.