# Getting a timestamp from VLC into a word processor

Tags: microsoft-word, vlc-media-player, autohotkey, timestamp

I'd like to be able to get the current playing time of a file in VLC media player and insert it as a timestamp into a word processor - so something like a hotkey combination that will output "[HH:MM:SS]" at the current cursor position.

Is there any existing way to do this? If not, given something like AutoHotkey, how would I go about getting the current time out of VLC?

Comment: I suppose this would be possible, as AutoHotkey should be able to extract such information from the UI. However, Superuser is not a script writing service. Dig into the AutoHotkey documentation and forums and try out how far you get. Then someone might be able to help you. A Google search turned up this SU answer: http://superuser.com/questions/1026248/how-to-get-current-timestamp-in-vlc-player-without-using-gui

Comment: I wasn't looking for a script-writing service - just guidance, as someone who currently doesn't know how to write such a script, that this is the right tree to be barking up, or that someone else hasn't done this but using terms I don't know about and therefore can't search for :D  So, cheers, I'll keep going this way and see what I can work out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using AutoHotKey as shown below.

But this is somehow tricky since AFAIK there is no way to predict and positionate the focus in the time field. I think this is (at least in the german version) because there is no Alt-Key combination for it. There are only (aparently) two Alt-Key combinations: for the button "Los" (german for "OK") and for "Abbrechen (german for "Cancel"). The next problem is that the dialog is not modal and pressing Alt-Keys activates the menues on the main window.

Therefore I'm using `MouseClick` to click the time field. The coordinates may vary depending on the screen resolution. Please change this for your screen resolution. Evtl. use AutoHotKey's `WindowSpy` to get your coordinates

Furthermore I store the original contents of the clipboard and the mouse position at the beginning of the script and restore them at the end.

```ahk
; # Insert Timestamp from VLC
#ifWinActive ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE
F8::
    ; GoToTimeDialogName:="Zu Zeitpunkt gehen" ; # german name of "Go to Time" dialog
    GoToTimeDialogName:="Go to Time" ; # english name of "Go to Time" dialog
    ClipSaved := ClipboardAll ; # Save the entire clipboard
    MouseGetPos x, y ; # get current mouse position
    if WinExist("ahk_exe vlc.exe") { ; # if vlc existst, i.e. vlc is running
        WinActivate ; # activate vlc window
        Send, {Esc} ; # make sure you are not in other dialogs
        Send, ^t ; # open the "Go to Time" dialog
        if WinExist(GoToTimeDialogName) { ; # if the "Go to Time" dialog exists
            WinActivate ; # activate "Go to Time" dialog exists
            MouseClick, left, 120, 48 ; # click on time field (change this for other screen resolutions)
            Send, ^a ; # select time field
            Send, ^c ; # copy to clipboard
            ClipWait ; # Wait for the clipboard to contain text.
            ts:=clipboard ; # get content of clipboard to var "ts"
            Send, ^t ; # quit "Go to Time" dialog
        }
    }
    if WinExist("ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE") { ; # if word exists
        WinActivate  ; # activate word window
        Send, [%ts%]{space} ; # insert the timestamp surrounded by brackets and a space
    }
    Clipboard := ClipSaved   ; # Restore the original clipboard
    MouseMove %x%, %y% ; # move mouse to original position
Return
```